# how to store long textual description in graph database?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

For example, I have two nodes:

product hasProblem Problem

If i have a small paragraph to describe the Problem, how to store it in the Problem node? As a property, "description: ..."?

I am new to graph database, sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: Yes. Quite a few of these kinds of questions can be answered by reading the documentation, or downloading the community version and giving it a try yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a basic question that can be answered by reading the documentation or by trying out the community version of the product.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing text in Neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120506/storing-text-in-neo4j)